# Интересная задачка. Списки участников олимпиад

Tags: c++

Помогите разобраться в задачке, пожалуйста
Дан список пофамильный участников олимпиад по математике, информатике, физике, химии и
биологии. На каждой олимпиаде было по 5 заданий. Известны оценки каждого из участников по
каждому заданию. Вывести фамилии учеников, набравших максимальные суммы баллов для каждой
из олимпиад.

Comment: Приведите свои попытки решения задачи, и конкретную проблему,  которая возникла при решении.

Comment: Да не, совсем неинтересная.